# Using Android Presentation class with a Bluetooth mouse

Tags: android, bluetooth, mouse, presentation

I am attempting to use the [Presentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) class for Android to display a secondary app on another display which can be navigated with the mouse; however, when I connect a Bluetooth mouse to the phone it only shows the cursor and allows for click inputs on the phone's primary display. Is there a way to override the display the mouse cursor shows up on in such a way that I can feed it my Presentation display information and have it show up on the cast display instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Android does not yet allow for this kind of system manipulation. Hopefully in a later version they will implement some better mouse controls.